# Changing Input Of Invisible Neiron

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I am trying to make a neiron net on Python. I have already make two classes: Neiron(it's an analogue of Invisible Neiron) and InputNeiron. Input Neiron works well but Neiron not.
The problem is that after Operate() Input of this Neiron change. How can i fix it? What is it caused by? (I am new in programming and i am not English native speaker :D )
Code here:

```
  import random
import math

class Neiron():
 Input = 0
 TargetNeiron = {}
 def Func(self, x):
  return (1/(1+ math.exp(-1*x)))
 def __init__(self, *neirons):
  for neiron in neirons:
   self.TargetNeiron[neiron] = random.triangular(0,100)
 def Operate(self):
  a = self.Func(self.Input)
  print(a)
  for neiron in self.TargetNeiron:
   neiron.Input = neiron.Input + (self.TargetNeiron[neiron] * a)


class InputNeiron(Neiron):
 def Func(self, x):
  if str(type(x)) == "<class 'str'>":
   return 1;
  else:
   if x < 1:
    return x;
   else:
    return 1/x;


b = Neiron()
a = Neiron(b);
c = InputNeiron(b,a)

try:
 c.Input = float(input('Input = '))
except:
 c.Input = 1;

print('target Neirons of c, first b, second a:',c.TargetNeiron)
print('Input of a before c.Operate:', a.Input)
print('Input of b before c.Operate:', b.Input)
c.Operate()
print('Input of a after c.Operate:', a.Input)
print('Input of b after c.Operate:', b.Input)
a.Operate()
print('Input of a after a.Operate:', a.Input)
print('Input of b after a.Operate:', b.Input)
```

Neiron(a) or InputNeiron(a) means that this neiron will be connected to a.
TargetNeirons is a dictionary with {neiron: synaptic multiplier} paars. Func is a special function. She is different for Neiron and InputNeiron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the `Input` field of your `Neiron` changes after each call of `n.Operate()` is this peace of code, which changes it..

```
for neiron in self.TargetNeiron:
  neiron.Input = neiron.Input + (self.TargetNeiron[neiron] * a)
```

As for the 'how can I fix it?' I suppose you could overwrite the `Operate` function for the `InputNeiron` class if you want to keep only the input for c constant, otherwise you would have to change the function `Operate` in the `Neiron` class to leave `neiron.Input` alone.

In general I would highly recommend you check out existing implementations of artificial neural nets for example at [scikit learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html).

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. I have added in Neiron.__init___ deleting TargetNeiron[self]. And now it's working good!!! Thanks for you help.